# How to solve red power light of my router?

Tags: router, ip, power

My router is D-Link 2700U. Whenever I turn it off, it fails to be turned on again and the power led becomes red instead of green. I have to reboot it about 10 times or more so that it works properly.

After many times of rebooting, the power light becomes green but the router does not work properly. I can access the internet through wifi only. I can't access the internet using the two computers that are connected to the router. It says "Unidentified network" and the computer behaves as if I entered a wrong IP address.

I tried to reset the router. After resetting, I upload a small backup file that contains some data about my ISP to be able to access the internet. Uploading this file requires the router to reboot. It can't easily reboot so the resetting process was so hard for me and I prefer not to do it again. Resetting doesn't solve the problem.

Could you have me, please?

Comment: `POWER - Red Solid Light - Not bootable or device malfunction.` - Have you tried to update the firmware? Here is the link: http://www.dlink.com.sg/dsl-2700u/#firmware

Comment: The router is kind of locked by the ISP because I got it for free from my ISP. I tried to update the software in the past but I couldn't. Anyway, I'll try once again. Thank you,

Comment: How do you power it off? Do you use an on/off switch, or do you physically remove the power lead? Try doing the latter, leaving it disconnected for 30 seconds. If this doesn't work, report the faulty router to your ISP. If it's part of your service deal, they should replace it.

Comment: @AFH I use the switch most of the time. I'll try your solution. Unfortunately, it's not a part of the service deal but I can pay to get it fixed. I asked this question to make sure if it's a real problem with the hardware, not the software. Thanks :)

Comment: You may want to try going back to factory settings to see if this improves matters, but put in your custom settings manually, not by restoring from a saved configuration file. If matters don't improve, depending what the ISP will charge, you may prefer independently to buy a new router, which will give you a warranty and avoid service interruption. The 2700U is not available in UK, but a slightly better-specified router is available here for under £50.

Comment: @AFH Okay, thank you so much for your comments and for your time. I really appreciate that.